# What is the expanded code from this lambda method?

Tags: android, lambda, rx-java2

I'm trying to use Rx2Animations Library, but it's uses Lambda variables in their samples. So, I don't know very well how to expand that lambdas in regular code.

The example:

```
package oxim.digital.rx2animations.colorpicker;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;

public final class ColorPickerPresenter extends BasePresenter<ColorPickerContract.View> implements ColorPickerContract.Presenter {

    @Override
    public void refreshView() {
        final ColorPickerContract.View view = getNullableView();
        if (view == null) {
            return;
        }

        final Disposable animationDisposable = view.setupInitialAnimation()
                .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .concatWith(view.startInitialAnimation())
                .subscribe(this::onAnimationEnd, Throwable::printStackTrace);

        addSubscription(animationDisposable);
    }

    private void onAnimationEnd() {

    }

}
```

Inside subscribe method appears the lambda.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first lambda is the `onNext()` handler,  `this::onAnimationEnd()` is method reference that execute `onAnimationEnd` method, you have compile error here as onNext emits some object, so the method should have matching param:
 `private void onAnimationEnd(EmittedObject o)`
 (in this sample code it's `EmittedObject` but it should be the actual Object type that your `Observable` emits).
The second lambda param is the `onError()` notification handler, which is also method reference, this time to the `Throwable.printStackTrace()` method.

Generally speaking, the IDE (Android Studio) is your best friend, you can just let it auto generate your code based on the signature you choose)

```
  final Disposable animationDisposable = view.setupInitialAnimation()
            .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .concatWith(view.startInitialAnimation())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<EmittedObject>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull EmittedObject o) throws Exception {
                    onAnimationEnd(o);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```